# How to fix no. of ticks on X Axis in Bar Chart using d3?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I have a bar chart which shows time on X-axis in gap of 1 unit(i.e. either 1 hr, or 1 day). It becomes cluttered and overlaps when X axis domain grows. P.s. attached snapshots
[image: duration gap is one day]

[image: duration gap isfive days]

[image: duration gap is one month]

I want to avoid this overlapping behaviour and set ticks to 5, no matter the domain.
My code-
https://codesandbox.io/s/mq922ymkpy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

d3 `ticks` is considered a "hint" - not an upper bound, and will in fact change based on the domain. If you want to completely force the ticks, you should use `tickValues` with some logic to get N values from the data at positions you want.

For example:

```
const indicesBetweenPoints = Math.round(this.props.data.length / 5)
const xAxis = d3
  .axisBottom(x)
  .tickFormat(timeFormat)
  .tickValues(
    this.props.data.map((d, i) =>
      i % indicesBetweenPoints == 0 ? d[this.props.xAxis] : undefined).filter(item => item)
  );
```

Comment: It works nicely. Thank you. So dividing by 5 means we want multiples of 5? Please explain.

Comment: Dividing by 5 means we want a maximum of 5 points. If we have 50 items, then we divide by the number of points (5) - we get the result of 10, this means that for tickValues we need to take a value every 10 items from the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

`svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis x")
      .attr("transform",`translate(0, ${height})`)
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("x", 25)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("font-family", "ibm-plex-sans")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(90)");`

Comment: I tried this. It works fine for this dataset, but when the gap is of a year or more, X-axis is cluttered. Thanks anyway